# Clipperlib is not behaving as intended when doing a union on a multipolygon

Tags: c#, computational-geometry, geojson, clipperlib

I am trying to union a multipolygon but it is not working well as shown in the picture below:

[image]

The code I am using is:

```
using ClipperLib;
using Polygon = System.Collections.Generic.List<ClipperLib.IntPoint>;
using Polygons = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<ClipperLib.IntPoint>>;

namespace Ylp.ComputationalGeometry
{
    public static class Merge
    {
        public static IList<IList<double>> Multipolygon(IList<IList<IList<IList<double>>>> multiPolygon)
        {
            const double precisionFactor = 1000000000000000.0;

            //precondition: all your polygons have the same orientation 
            //(ie either clockwise or counter clockwise)
            Polygons polys = new Polygons();

            multiPolygon.ForEach(x =>
            {
                Polygon polygon = x.First().Select( y => new IntPoint()
                {
                    X = (long)(y[0] * precisionFactor),
                    Y = (long)(y[1] * precisionFactor)
                }).ToList();

                polys.Add(polygon);
            });

            Polygons solution = new Polygons();
            Clipper c = new Clipper();
            c.AddPaths(polys, PolyType.ptSubject,true);
            c.Execute(ClipType.ctUnion, solution,
                PolyFillType.pftNonZero, PolyFillType.pftNonZero);

            var coordinates = solution.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y=> (IList<double>)new List<double>()
            {
                y.X / precisionFactor,
                y.Y / precisionFactor
            }).ToList()) .ToList();

            return coordinates;
        }
    }
}
```

What I really want the oucome of the union to look like is something like the following, so any intersections in the middle should be ignored and an area covering both shapes should be created:

[image]

and the original shape is:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are merging multiple polygons into a single polygon. Also try using real types not lists of lists of lists.

Comment: The result of your union certainly doesn't look right so it'd be helpful if you could post a link to your coordinate data. Having said that it seems you're really after the outline of the set of polygons but I'm afraid the Clipper library doesn't help you there.

Comment: @AngusJohnson Hi there, maybe you can help me with this question, would really appreciate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185891/making-holes-in-geojson-shapes-clipperlib

Comment: @Xerxes I can't help unless you can upload the data (polygon coordinates) somewhere and provide a link to it.

Comment: @AngusJohnson the file is attached to the question, it is a geojson file with all the coordinates for all the shapes.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185891/making-holes-in-geojson-shapes-clipperlib

Comment: @Xerxes I was asking for in the coordinates for the polygons displayed in **this** question - ie for polygons displayed in the images above. There certainly appears to be a couple of peculiar (incorrect) intersections and you imply that this is due to a bug in Clipper. (The data you supplied in your other question doesn't help me with this one.)